# How to handle client abort during request upload?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-4

Given the following application, based on a [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io) template

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    public static class Payload {
        public String field1;
        public String field2;
    }

    @RestController
    public static class MyController {
        @RequestMapping("/echo")
        public ResponseEntity<Payload> echo(@RequestBody Payload payload) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(payload, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

If I abort the connection after sending the headers

```
$ nc 192.168.56.1 8080
POST /echo HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.56.1:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 42

^C
```

Then the server attempts to respond with a 400 and the following is logged

```
2016-05-03 16:56:28.916  WARN 5776 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unexpected EOF read on the socket; nested exception is java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
2016-05-03 16:56:28.997 ERROR 5776 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error] org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

If instead the client aborts after the request has been sent, nothing is logged by default and the resulting `ClientAbortException` is available in filters via `ErrorAttributes#getError`.

How can I handle the during-request abort in the same way? That is, not having any warn/error logged by default, and to enable custom filters to tell that the client has aborted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution, and have yet to find a case where it does the wrong thing.

```java
@Autowired
private DefaultErrorAttributes defaultExceptionResolver;
    
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public void checkForAbort(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, RuntimeException exception) {
    if (exception.getCause() instanceof EOFException) {
        ClientAbortException abortException = new ClientAbortException(exception.getCause());
        abortException.addSuppressed(exception);
        try {
            response.getOutputStream().close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            abortException.addSuppressed(ex);
        }

        defaultExceptionResolver.resolveException(request, response, null, abortException);
    }
    else {
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

This could would go in, for example, a `@ControllerAdvice`.