# Spring Boot, Tomcat, REST, handling client timeout on server side

Tags: java, rest, sockets, spring-boot, tomcat

I want to ask you about a case, when client timeouts during the request due to short read timeout, broken connection or whatever. We have a REST microservice, which has to have assurance that response was received by the client.

When we tested this scenario by setting short read timeout on the client, there was no error on server side that client is unavailable. We expected some IOException or ClientAbortException thrown by tomcat, but the only thing we've got was silently catching the IOException in action() method of tomcat's AbstractProcessor class and not propagating this exception further.

Could you tell us what should be the default behaviour in Tomcat+Spring Boot, when client connection is broken during the request? Or do you have any ideas how to be aware of broken connection during the request?

We use Spirng Boot 1.5.12 with Tomcat 8.5.29

Sample of the problem:

- Client

  ```
  HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
  requestFactory.setReadTimeout(500);

  TestRestTemplate corruptestTestRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate(restTemplate.getRestTemplate());
  corruptestTestRestTemplate.getRestTemplate().setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

  RequestTest request = new RequestTest();
  request.field = "abc";

  ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> response = null;

  try {
      response = corruptestTestRestTemplate.postForEntity(URI, request, ErrorResponse.class);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  try {
      Thread.sleep(Duration.ofMinutes(1).toMillis());
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```
- Server

  ```
  @PostMapping("/sampleUri")
  public ResponseEntity<SampleResponse> sample(@Valid @RequestBody SampleRequest request){
          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          SampleResponse response = service.sample(request) 
          return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
  }
  ```
- Stacktrace from client as expected:

  ```
  org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:49963/sampleUri": Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:674)
      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621)
      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:415)
      at org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.postForEntity(TestRestTemplate.java:471)
      at com.example.rest.IntTest.sample_withShortClientTimeout_expectIOException(IntTest.java:152)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
      at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
      at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
      at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
      at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
      at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
      at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
  Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
      at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
      at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
      at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
      at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
      at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
      at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
      at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
      at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
      at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
      at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
      at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
      at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:89)
      at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
      at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:660)
      ... 32 more
  ```
- No stacktrace from server

PS: ClientAbortException is raised, only when processing from server-side is longer than connection-timeout(default 60s). But when for example server processes request for 10s, and client read timeout is 5s, then there is no exception on server-side.

Comment: Have you checked this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009285/how-to-handle-client-abort-during-request-upload

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that exception is thrown and caught on tomcat level libraries and it is not propagated further, so we cant access it. 

To be more precise, the exception is thrown by org.apache.catalina.connector.Response#finishResponse and it is caught by org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor#action.

Comment: Perhaps you can share a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve)? As shown in the question that's linked to by @BehnamSafari, a `ClientAbortException` is expected in situations like this one.

Comment: Ok, I added how to reproduce this problem